# Two template template parameters and one requires the other

Tags: c++

This is very difficult to describe. I have a class (`Duo`) with two template template parameters. One of the classes is the parameter to the other, but it's still not fully-defined yet, until we're inside `Holder`, where I then instantiate `Solid` with a template parameter only `Holder` knows.

```
template<class T>
struct Solid
{
    T _t;
};

template<template<typename> class SE>
struct Holder
{
    SE<int> _se;
};

template<template<typename> class HOLD,
         template<typename> class S>
struct Duo 
{
    HOLD<S> _mem;
};


int main()
{
    Duo<Holder, Solid> a;
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get this compiler error:

```
   29 |     HOLD<S> _mem;
      |              ^
main.cpp:29:14: note:   expected a type, got ‘S’
```

Is there a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 5):

The parameter of `HOLD` has to be a template rather than a type:

```
template<
    template<template <typename> class> class HOLD,
    template<typename> class S
>
struct Duo
```

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you so much. I will accept but have to wait 9 mins.

Comment: Holy cow! template, template, template, and a SNAAAAAKE!
Nice anwser.